# Comment replies do not generate red dot on Stack Exchange button (but do show up in inbox)

Tags: support, comments, notifications, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

I've noticed in the past few hours that comment replies are not causing the notification red dot & number to show up. However, on my account page, the red square counter on the Responses tab does show up, and after clicking on the Stack Exchange button and going to my inbox, I see the comment reply there.

I haven't noticed / checked yet whether this is occurring with any other class of events that normally creates a notification red dot. (**Edit:** I just got the Civic Duty badge on TeX.SE, and the *pale blue* dot notifying of a new badge is working for me.)

Is anyone else seeing similar behavior?

I'm using Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Comment: It is working for me (using Chrome)

Comment: Really? It works for me (just commenting to give you a test case).

Comment: Thanks for the test :) I can confirm that neither of the two comments above made a notification red dot, but do show up in the inbox.

Comment: Did you expand the global inbox in some other tab/browser? Then the red dot won't be shown any more, because the messages will automatically be marked as "read".

Comment: @RobW: Aha, I think that's it! I had a massive number of tabs open and one of them had the inbox expanded. I've checked that the inbox is closed everywhere now. Could you post another comment so I can confirm it's working now?

Comment: @ZevChonoles I believe that it's working. I have experienced it myself too often.

Comment: @RobW: Indeed, it's working now. Thanks for your help! Please feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've expanded the global inbox in one of your opened Stack Exchange tabs, causing notifications to be marked as read. Close this box, and the healthy red dot will show up again.

It would make sense if the messages are not fetched when the tab is currently inactive. The [Page Visibility API](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/) (<sup>[have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060034)</sup>) can be used for this purpose (did I hear a Feature request?).

PS. You might like my [Real-time Desktop notifications for your SE inbox](https://stackapps.com/q/3780/9699?real-time-desktop-notifications-for-stack-exchange-inbox) extension (Chrome/Firefox).

Comment: I was able to immediately see that you posted an answer because I am getting my notifications now :) Thanks again!

Comment: Shameless and blantant self promotion. I *love* it. ;).